# Hover at 1 image in mutil images of canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova, canvas

I am try writing a demo using hover in canvas.

This is the problem:

- I have 1 canvas and in this have 2 images.

- I want when i hover in 1 of 2 images this change (in this case is change color).

But when i hover all the canvas change.My canvas have 1 id, so i dont know how to do this.

This is my hover:

```
 $("#after_image").hover(function() {
        setFilter(red);
    }, function() {
        setFilter(grayscale);
    });
```

This is my screen when not hover and hover:
[image]

[image]

I follow the tutorial at here:

http://www.storminthecastle.com/2013/04/06/how-you-can-do-cool-image-effects-using-html5-canvas/

I am dumper, please help me!

Thanks for read. :)

Answer (score 1):

That is the way it's supposed to be as "#after_image" contains both of those images. Create new canvas elements for additional images and you should be good to go once you add hover events for them.

Could even add a class instead of ID and use $(this)

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for your help! But i dont want more canvas. Have any way to do it in 1 canvas?

Comment: Yes sir, there is. You'd need to do it through the javascript itself which I'm guessing you've already begun to modify? The reason I assume so is that the filehelper included in your demo only accepts one file, and you're uploading two it seems? Looking at the sample link you provide, it looks like the source would need a significant rewrite as it applys itself to the entire canvas object instead of the image object it draws inside of it. Good Luck!